# How to combine page url and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have link that need url of the page, how to get the page url then insert in the link url with JavaScript?

For example, if the page url is `http://example.com/blabla/blablabla/bla/`

and i don't know how to make JavaScript that combine page url and JavaScript.

```
<a href="http://link.cut/abc=<script>window.location.href</script>" rel="nofollow">GoToLink</a>
```

to link like this

```
<a href="http://link.cut/abc=http://example.com/blabla/blablabla/bla/">GoToLink</a>
```

```
<a href="http://link.cut/abc=http://example.com/blabla/blablabla/bla/">GoToLink</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give it an ID then manipulate throw javascript

```
<a id="a1" href="#" rel="nofollow">GoToLink</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("a1").href="http://link.cu/abc="+window.location.href; 

</script>
```